# What is the difference between ndarray and array in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

What is the difference between [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) and [`array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) in NumPy? Where is their implementation in the NumPy source code?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

`numpy.array` is just a convenience function to create an `ndarray`; it is not a class itself.

You can also create an array using `numpy.ndarray`, but it is not the recommended way.  From the docstring of `numpy.ndarray`:

> Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty` ...  The parameters given here refer to a
>   low-level method (`ndarray(...)`) for instantiating an array.

Most of the meat of the implementation is in C code, [here in multiarray](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray), but you can start looking at the ndarray interfaces here:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py

Comment: I think array() is implemented in [core/src/multiarray/methods.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c) in array_getarray().

Comment: This can bite you if you forget that `np.array` is not a class, as I often do.
`x = np.array([1,2.1,3])`
`if isinstance(x,np.array): # will give you a TypeError`

Comment: Still have no clue why should avoid using ndarray? Coz it's low-level?

Comment: @flxb: No, `array_getarray` is the implementation of `numpy.ndarray.__array__`. `numpy.array` starts at [`_array_fromobject`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1648), at least in the current implementation.

Comment: So why is it not recommended?

Comment: Usually when you have a type (i.e. `ndarray`) which is complicated to construct factory methods such as `array`,`zeros` etc are provided to ensure that it's constructed correctly. Also perhaps the numpy developers prefer to keep the interfaces of `array`,`zeros` unchanged from release to release but don't make the same guarantees of `ndarray()`

Answer (score 82):

`numpy.array` is a function that returns a `numpy.ndarray` object.

There is no object of type `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 54):

Just a few lines of example code to show the difference between numpy.array and numpy.ndarray

**Warm up step: Construct a list**

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

Check the type

```
print(type(a))
```

You will get

```
<class 'list'>
```

**Construct an array (from a list) using np.array**

```
a = np.array(a)
```

Or, you can skip the warm up step, directly have

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Check the type

```
print(type(a))
```

You will get

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

which tells you **the type of the numpy array is numpy.ndarray**

You can also check the type by

```
isinstance(a, (np.ndarray))
```

and you will get

```
True
```

Either of the following two lines will give you an error message

```
np.ndarray(a)                # should be np.array(a)
isinstance(a, (np.array))    # should be isinstance(a, (np.ndarray))
```

Answer (score 16):

`numpy.ndarray()` is a class, while `numpy.array()` is a method / function to create `ndarray`.

In numpy docs if you want to create an array from `ndarray` class you can do it with 2 ways as quoted:

1- using `array()`, `zeros()` or `empty()` methods:
*Arrays should be constructed using array, zeros or empty (refer to the See Also section below). The parameters given here refer to a low-level method (`ndarray(…)`) for instantiating an array.*

2- from `ndarray` class directly:
*There are two modes of creating an array using `__new__`:
    If buffer is None, then only shape, dtype, and order are used.
    If buffer is an object exposing the buffer interface, then all keywords are interpreted.*

The example below gives a random array because we didn't assign buffer value:

> ```
> np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F', buffer=None)
>
> array([[ -1.13698227e+002,   4.25087011e-303],
>        [  2.88528414e-306,   3.27025015e-309]])         #random
> ```

another example is to assign array object to the buffer
example:

> ```
> >>> np.ndarray((2,), buffer=np.array([1,2,3]),
> ...            offset=np.int_().itemsize,
> ...            dtype=int) # offset = 1*itemsize, i.e. skip first element
> array([2, 3])
> ```

from above example we notice that we can't assign a list to "buffer" and we had to use numpy.array() to return ndarray object for the buffer

Conclusion: use `numpy.array()` if you want to make a `numpy.ndarray()` object"

Answer (score -3):

I think with `np.array()` you can only create C like though you mention the order, when you check using `np.isfortran()` it says false. but with `np.ndarrray()` when you specify the order it creates based on the order provided.