# Numpy does not create binary file

Tags: python, numpy

When trying to write numpy matrix `M` to binary file as:

```
from io import open
X = [random.randint(0, 2 ** self.stages - 1)for _ in range(num)]
Matrix = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X])

file_output = open('result.bin', 'wb')
M = np.ndarray(Matrix, dtype=np.float64)
file_output.write(M)
file_output.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiments.py", line 164, in <module>
    write_data(X, y)
  File "experiments.py", line 39, in write_data
    arr = np.ndarray(Matrix, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

Can I know how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: pls fix your code (e.g. file name) first.

Comment: You forgot to open a string. Please fix that first.

Comment: Oh! Thank you . but still have same problem

Comment: The error occurs in `arr = np.ndarray(Matrix, dtype=np.float64)`.  We need to know what `Matrix` is.  Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems the problem is with using `np.ndarray`. An answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879315/what-is-the-difference-between-ndarray-and-array-in-numpy) question suggests to not use this, instead, use `np.array`

Comment: I even cut-and-pasted the line, and somehow missed the `nd` in `ndarray`.  @DavidG is correct--don't use `np.ndarray` like that, use `np.array`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have updated my post. Thank you

Comment: This question isn't about saving an array, it's about correctly generating some sort of random array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of two equivalent ways:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))
a.tofile('test1.dat')

with open('test2.dat', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(a.tobytes())

# diff test1.dat test2.dat
```

See the docs for [`tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html). However from the original example, it looks like `Matrix` is failing to be convert into an `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
M = np.ndarray(Matrix, dtype=np.float64)
```

with

```
M = Matrix.astype(np.float64)
```

`np.array(Matrix, dtype=np.float64)` would also work, but the `astype` is simpler.

I'm having some problems recreating your `Matrix` variable.  What's its shape?

`np.save` is the best way of saving a multidimensional array to a file. There are other methods, but they don't save the shape and dtype information.

---

`ndarray` is wrong because the first (positional) argument is supposed to be the shape, not another array.  The data if any is provided in the `buffer` parameter.  `ndarray` is not normally used by beginners or even advanced numpy users.

---

What is `Matrix` supposed to be.  When I try your code with a couple of parameters, I get an error in the `map` step:

```
In [495]: X = [np.random.randint(0, 2 ** 2 - 1)for _ in range(4)]
     ...: Matrix = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X])
     ...: 
-----> 2 Matrix = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X])
....
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
In [496]: X
Out[496]: [1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Is `X` just a list of numbers?  Not some sort of list of arrays?  And why the `Matrix` step?  Is it trying to convert a nested list of lists into integers?  Even though `randint` already creates integers?  Then you follow with a conversion to `float`?