# Python How to convert ['0.12' '0.23'] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> to a normal numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I am using a package that is fetching values from a csv file for me. If I print out the result I get `['0.12' '0.23']`. I checked the type, which is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` I want to convert it to a numpy array like `[0.12, 0.23]`.
I tried `np.asarray(variabel)` but that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: They are the same thing? `a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); print(type(a))`. Yours just happens to contain strings. Just do `a = a.astype(np.float64)`. You haven't stated what the problem is.

Comment: @roganjosh: Thank you for your comment, but `a = a.astype(np.float64)` does not add the comma. It generates  `[1 2 3]`

Comment: What is the issue though? That's entirely visual; lists don't physically contain commas either, it's just so that you can see individual elements. You already _have_ a normal numpy array, there is no conversion to actually do other than convert the type. The only other thing I can suggest is `a.tolist()` after the conversion but.... well, that's no longer an array.

Comment: @roganjosh: If I want to calculate with it it gives me an error `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Then you're completely misdiagnosing your issue and the necessary information is missing from the question to solve the real problem.

Comment: @roganjosh: You were right! Thank you for your help. If you answer this question I would accept your answer, because you were the first to answer it in the comment.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what issue I solved. I have left a dupe target; if that answers your question then you can unilaterally accept that dupe and it gives all the detail needed for future readers. Otherwise, feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: I don't think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879315/what-is-the-difference-between-ndarray-and-array-in-numpy answers this question.  Most of the answers go down a rabbit-trail of when to use `np.array` versus `np.ndarray` constructors.  I'm reopening so someone can write a answer that builds on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
import numpy as np
array = array.astype(np.float)


# If you are just initializing array you can do this
ar= np.array(your_list,dtype=np.float)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to know how the `csv` was read.  But for what ever reason it appears to have created a `numpy` array with a string `dtype`:

```
In [106]: data = np.array(['0.12', '0.23'])
In [107]: data
Out[107]: array(['0.12', '0.23'], dtype='<U4')
In [108]: print(data)
['0.12' '0.23']
```

The `str` formatting of such an array omits the comma, the `repr` display keeps it.

A list equivalent also displays with comma:

```
In [109]: data.tolist()
Out[109]: ['0.12', '0.23']
```

We call this a numpy array, but technically it is of class `numpy.ndarray`

```
In [110]: type(data)
Out[110]: numpy.ndarray
```

It can be converted to an array of floats with:

```
In [111]: data.astype(float)
Out[111]: array([0.12, 0.23])
```

It is still a `ndarray`, just the `dtype` is different.  You may need to read more in the `numpy` docs about `dtype`.

The error:

> If I want to calculate with it it gives me an error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

has a different source.  `data` has 2 elements. You don't show the code that generates this error, but often we see this in plotting calls.  The parameter is supposed to be a single number (often an integer), where as your array, even with a numeric `dtype`) is two numbers.