# Numpy For Large Data Sets

Tags: python, numpy

For generating a probability density function of some cases, maybe 1 million observations are considered. When I work with numpy array, I was encountered by size limit 32.

Is it too few ?

In this case, how can we store more than 32 elements without distributing the elements into different columns and maybe arrays in arrays ?

```
import numpy
my_list = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    my_list.append(i)

np_arr = numpy.ndarray(np_arr) # ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What are "elements" here?

Comment: Any interpretation I can make of the question suggests that no such limit exists

Comment: Did you get an error message? Where is your code?

Comment: How are you creating the array? The only limitation to Numpy array size is your hardware resources. You should have no problem with 1M elements.  `np.zeros(1e6)` will created an array with a million zeros. Give it a try.

Comment: I added a code right now

Comment: You did not specify how `np_arr` variable was defined in your code.

Comment: @Goktug: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879315/what-is-the-difference-between-ndarray-and-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array with `numpy.ndarray`, the first argument is the shape of the array.  Interpreting that list as a shape would indeed give a huge array.  If you just want to turn the list into an array, you want `numpy.array`:

```
import numpy
my_list = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    my_list.append(i)

np_arr = numpy.array(my_list)
```

Comment: You don't need to create a list...just use arange; `np_arr = numpy.arange(100)` (for int32) or `np_arr = numpy.arange(100.0)` (for float64).

Comment: @kcw78 I believe the OP's error is coming up because they are using the wrong function to convert a list into an array.  My answer aims to show the right way to make that conversion.

Comment: Good point. It wasn't clear why the OP used a list to create an array. If he really needs to convert a list, then he should follow your steps. If he just needs an array with [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...100], he can use arange(). Will leave that for OP to figure out.

Comment: I assumed that the "real" code has a more complicated list and that `range` was just a convenient way to make a [mcve].  I could be completely wrong of course!