# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer Python NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Is there any way to turn a list of strings into a `numpy.ndarray`?. Because I tried this code:

```py
All  = np.ndarray([str(necessary_lines).split(',')])
```

Which gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Coding/Python/somePythonProgram.py", line 47, in <module>
    print(parseCSV(file))
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Coding/Python/somePythonProgram.py", line 34, in somePythonProgram
    All  = np.ndarray([str(necessary_lines).split(',')])
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Or is it that you can't turn a list of strings into a numpy array?

Comment: What is your `necessary_lines`?

Comment: Why the `[,]` in `[str(necessary_lines).split(',')]`? `.split()` already returns a list, you don't need to stick it into another. In any event, please provide a [mcve]. We shouldn't need to guess about what your data is.

Comment: Necessary_lines is a list of filtered lines of a CSV document (filtered as in the blank lines are removed). But then I want the csv values themself, seperated in their own array(to represent each line).

Comment: Also -- your traceback doesn't match your posted code.

Comment: Oh yeah, I removed some stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `np.array` instead of `np.ndarray`. Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467874/12981435).
Also, you can use `np.asarray()`.

Comment: If my answer solver your first problem, please upvote and then post your new problem.

Comment: Don't worry, I finished the program. It's now working perfectly. Thanks for the help!